# len(list) in python returns 1 instead of 0

Tags: python, glassfish-3

We are trying to count the instances in glassfish. When using the len() function this always returns 1 instead of 0. Maybe it fills the list[0] with an empty space or something. This is our code.

```
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(self.get('hostname'),int(self.get('port')),self.get('username'),allow_agent=True)
    #try:
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('~/glassfish3/glassfish/bin/asadmin list-instances')
    result = stdout.readlines()
    #except Exception, e:
    #   return MonitoringResult(MonitoringResult.OK,'all instances up!')
    result = "".join(result)
    #line = re.compile(r'\bnot\s\D*\n')

    #rline = "".join(line.findall((result)))
    line2=re.compile(r'\bnot')
    rline2 = ";".join(line2.findall((result)))
    print(rline2)
    i = 0
    listr = rline2.split(";")

    while(i < (len(listr)):
        i+=1
    print(i)

    if rline2:
        return MonitoringResult(MonitoringResult.CRITICAL,'instance down')
    else:
        return MonitoringResult(MonitoringResult.OK, 'All instances are up')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `str.split` *cannot be* an empty `list`:

```
>>> ''.split(';')
['']
```

If you want to check whether the list obtained contains `any` non-empty string, use `any`:

```
>>> any(''.split(';'))
False
>>> any('a;'.split(';'))
True
>>> ';'.split(';')
['', '']
>>> any(';'.split(';'))
False
```

If you want to `filter` out the empty strings, use `filter`:

```
>>> filter(None, ';'.split(';'))
[]
```

Or a list-comprehension:

```
>>> [s for s in ';'.split(';') if s]
[]
```

---

I just realized that `str.split` *can* return an empty list. But *only* when called without an argument:

```
>>> ''.split()
[]
>>> '    '.split()   #white space string
[]
```

The explanation is in the documentation:

> `S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings`
>
> Return a list of the words in the string `S`, using `sep` as the
>   delimiter string.  If `maxsplit` is given, at most `maxsplit` splits
>   are done. If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, any whitespace
>   string is a separator **and empty strings are removed from the
>   result.**